# Run event whenever date changes in a cell A1

Tags: excel, vba

Need your input on how to run an Event whenever the date on cell A1 changes. The current formula in cell A1 is =Today().

This code doesn't work on me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then

    MsgBox "Another day has come!"

  End If

End Sub
```

Ex. What will happen should be, if it's 11:59 PM (Jun 11, 2019) and goes to the next day, 12:00 AM (Jun 12, 2019) a procedure will automatically run.

Thanks guys.

Comment: [Worksheet Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) doesn't fire when a formula recalculates. You need [Worksheet Calculate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate%28even%29).

Answer (score 2):

I would use **B1** as a "memory" cell.  Using BigBen's suggestion:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If [B1] = "" Then
            [B1] = [A1]
        ElseIf [B1] <> [A1] Then
            [B1] = [A1]
            MsgBox "Another day has come!"
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll check this out. Looks promising. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, use Application.ontime to run every day:

```
Public myBool As Boolean
Sub StartNextday()
    If myBool Then MsgBox "Another day has come!"
        Application.OnTime TimeSerial(0, 0, 0), "StartNextday"
        myBool = True
End Sub
Sub CloseNextday()
        Application.OnTime TimeSerial(0, 0, 0), "StartNextday", , False
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll have a look on this too. I'll just wait for the next day just to make sure. Thank you! :)

Comment: @jjacker YW, You can also change the Time in Timeserial => TimeSerial(20, 10, 0) for 20:10:00 to test it. An advantage over the Calculate-method is that it runs at 00:00, The calculate method will run after a (forced) recalculation,